# Use of Matlab find function for getting index of a vertex using its coordinates

Tags: matlab, find, mesh, surface, vertex

I have a matrix 50943x3 that contains vertices of a surface mesh.I want to find the index of a certain vertex using its coordinates (x,y,z).

I tried the Matlab function find but it return an empty matrix 0-by-1.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Comment: You should post your code to show what has been attempted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt probably does not work because of floating point rounding errors. You can read more about it [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/57444-faq-why-is-0-3-0-2-0-1-not-equal-to-zero). You could look into the the [eps function](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), or just use this example:

```
% Your matrix
M = randn(50943 , 3);

% The coordinates you are looking for
P = [0,0,0];

% Distance between all coordinates and target point
D = sqrt(sum((M - bsxfun(@minus,M,P)).^2,2));

% Closest coordinates to target
[~ , pos] = min(D);

% Display result
disp(M(pos , :))
```

Comment: `pos = find(D<tol);` where `tol` is a suitable tolerance would work too, in place of `[~ , pos] = min(D);`. It will sucessfully return 2 indices if there are two matching points, and and empty array if there is none, while `min` will always return one index. It depends whether these cases may be expected or not and what should be done in that case.

Comment: I used exactly this example to understand it but it returns a Matrix dimensions must agree error at the line `D = sqrt(sum((M - P).^2,2));`

Comment: @amine Probably a question of Matlab version; I corrected the example to make it compatible with older versions which do not automatically expand matrices.

Comment: @Brice, OP wants to find "find the index of a certain vertex" from its coordinates, not all the vertexes close to a given point. I think the solution should only return one point! Otherwise, yes, your modification would work.

Comment: @Zep, to be picky, to get compatibility with pre-R2016b versions of Matlab, it is adviseable to replace `(M-P)` with `bsxfun(@minus,M,P)` rather than using a `repmat`. Performance is better and the code shorter. And it is backward-compatible down to version R2007a.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
mat = randi(30,50943,3);
vec = [1,2,3];
% R2106b+ code
ind = find(all(mat==vec,2));
% or: explicit expansion, works with all versions
ind = find(all(bsxfun(@eq,mat,vec),2));
```

What it does:
`==` or `eq` will check if coordinates are equal (gives a [50943x3] bool matrix)
`all` will return true only if all coordinates are equal
`find` returns the index of all non zero elements

This works only for an exact match (hence the integer coordinates picked with `randi`).

---

Since the answer is already accepted, I'll add @Zep answer that provide a solution to get the nearest point, which seem to be what was initially sought.

```
[min_dist,ind_nearest] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus,mat,vec).^2,2)); % index to the nearest point
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Now, if `vec` does not exist in the `mat` matrix, how to get the nearest vertex ?

Comment: If you want the nearest, then use the answer from @Zep, computing the distance and looking for the minimum. This proposal will only work with an exact match (hence the example with `randi` and integer coordinates)

Comment: Yep it works, thank you for the two suggestions, I will keep it in mind